# slider, promlem ocurrance during slide

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
const body = document.querySelector(".body");
const leftListContainer = document.querySelector(".left-list");
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".list");
const conpart1 = document.querySelector(".conpart-1");
const conpart2 = document.querySelector(".conpart-2");
const conpart3 = document.querySelector(".conpart-3");
const conpic = document.querySelector(".sec-2-conpic");
const sec_2_inner=document.querySelector(".sec-2-inner")
const conpics=document.querySelectorAll(".conpics")
const conpic_1=document.querySelector(".conpic-1");
const conpic_2=document.querySelector(".conpic-2");
const conpic_3=document.querySelector(".conpic-3");
const conparts = document.querySelectorAll(".conpart");
const buttonRight = document.querySelector(".button-right");
const buttonLeft = document.querySelector(".button-left");
const Slider = document.querySelector(".slider");
const SliderCon = document.querySelector(".slider-con");
const sliderItems=document.querySelectorAll(".slider-item")
const sliderShell=document.querySelector(".slider-shell");
const sliderEl=document.querySelector(".slider-element");
const slider2Con=document.querySelector(".slider-container");
const con_2_Right=document.querySelector(".con-2-button-2")
const con_2_Left=document.querySelector(".con-2-button-1")
console.log(conpic_1.getBoundingClientRect());
console.log(conpic_2.getBoundingClientRect());
console.log(conpic_3.getBoundingClientRect());

const conpartFunction = function () {
  const containerWidth = sec_2_inner.offsetWidth;
  let lastClickedConpart = conpart1; // Set initial selected element

  // Add "selected" class to initial selected element
  lastClickedConpart.classList.add("selected");

  conparts.forEach((conpart) => {
    
    conpart.addEventListener("click", () => {
      if (lastClickedConpart !== conpart) {
        lastClickedConpart.classList.remove("selected");
      }
    
      conpart.classList.add("selected");
      lastClickedConpart = conpart;

      const index = Array.from(conparts).indexOf(conpart);
      const conpicRect = conpic.getBoundingClientRect();
      const scrollAmount =conpics[index].getBoundingClientRect().left ;

      // Smoothly scroll to the selected slide
      conpic.style.transition = "scrollLeft 0.5s ease-in-out";
      conpic.scrollLeft = scrollAmount;

      console.log(conpic_1.getBoundingClientRect());
console.log(conpic_2.getBoundingClientRect());
console.log(conpic_3.getBoundingClientRect());
    });
  });
};
conpartFunction();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
}
.nav {
  padding-top: 1.1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
  background-color: white;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9999;
}
.void {
  padding-right: 21.9%;
  padding-left: 20%;
}
.nav-lists {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: large;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.nav {
  padding-right: 17%;
  padding-left: 17%;
}
.list {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.list-logo {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.right-item {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  margin-left: 1em;
}
.hover {
  color: blue;
}
.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1685467212 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 210px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  z-index: 0;
}
.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1685467212 svg {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 1.3px);
  height: 160px;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.custom-shape-divider-bottom-1685467212 .shape-fill {
  fill: #ffffff;
}
.all {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(82, 67, 170), rgb(237, 80, 180));
  height: 70.8vh;
}
.content {
  margin-left: 21%;
  margin-right: 22%;
}
.section-1 {
  padding-top: 10vh;
  display: flex;
}
.wave-div {
  width: 70%;
  margin-right: 3em;
}
.img-div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.img-div {
  width: 90%;
}
.div-img {
  width: 100%;
}
.wave-header {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.wave-p {
  padding-top: 0.5em;
  font-size: 24px;
}
.mail-box {
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: flex;
}
.wave-email {
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0.8em;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.email-button {
  margin-left: 1em;
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 101, 255);
  color: white;
}
.button-curve {
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}
.section-1 {
  margin-bottom: 3em;
}
.sec-name {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.section-2 {
  margin-top: 3.6em;
}
.title {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.opening-2 {
  width: 55.5%;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.opening-parag {
  font-size: 21px;
}
.curver-div {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
.container-2 {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3em;
}
.sec-2-part {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 2.5%;
  width: 50.6%;
  height: 30rem;
}
.sec-2-conpic {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.sec-2-inner {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 width: 300%;

 transition: 1000ms;
}
.conpics{
  width: 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.conpicture{
  width: 100%;
}
.conpart {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 0.8em;
  padding-bottom: 0.8em;
  margin-bottom: 0.9em;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
.conpart:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.selected {
  border-left: 0.46em solid rgb(0, 199, 229);
  box-shadow: rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.15) 0px 0.5rem 1rem 0px;
}
.con-header {
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-bottom: 0.8em;
}
.con-content {
  font-size: 18px;
}
.container-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.conpic-1 {
  border-radius: none;
}
.show-con {
  padding-bottom: 7rem;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(230, 252, 255), rgb(255, 255, 255)) 0%
    0%;
}
.little-tag {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.big-title {
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin: 0.4em 0px;
}
.entry {
  margin-top: 4em;
}
.slider-shell {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.slider {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 740px;
  gap: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  transition: 1000ms;
}
.slide-right {
  margin-left: 1142px;
}
.slider-item {
  flex-basis: 22rem;
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  height: 15rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.15) 0px 0.5rem 1rem 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.slider-item:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.slider-darker {
  box-shadow: rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.3) 0px 0.5rem 1rem 0px;
}
.slider-head {
  height: 50px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}
.slider-title {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.slider-text {
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
.only-text {
  padding-left: 6px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  font-size: 600;
}
.slider-buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: end;
  gap: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-right: 21.9%;
  border: none;
}
.slider-button {
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
.slider-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button-img-left {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  width: 25px;
}
.button-img {
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.head1 {
  background: rgb(255, 116, 82);
}
.head2 {
  background: rgb(38, 132, 255);
}
.head3 {
  background: rgb(87, 217, 163);
}
.head4 {
  background: rgb(255, 196, 0);
}
.head5 {
  background: rgb(0, 199, 229);
}
.head6 {
  background: rgb(249, 156, 219);
}
.slider-img {
  width: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  top: 20px;
  left: 16px;
  border: 8px solid white;
  border-radius: 6px;
}
.slider-img img {
  width: 100%;
}
.slider-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.footer-closing {
  font-size: 21px;
  width: 50rem;
}
.footer-button {
  width: 13rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 101, 255);
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 350ms;
}
.footer-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(222, 235, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.view-con {
  background: linear-gradient(240deg, rgb(0, 184, 217), rgb(0, 101, 255));
  height: 64em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 15em;
}
.view-content {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 10;
}
.view-img1 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  height: 64em;
  left: 0px;
}
.view-img2 {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 64em;
  right: 0px;
}
.view-opening {
  padding-top: 3.3em;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.view-entering {
  text-align: center;
  width: 60%;
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.view-title {
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.view-button {
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 13px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  padding-right: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 101, 255);
  transition: 350ms;
}
.view-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(222, 235, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.presentation {
  background-color: white;
  height: 21em;
  width: 65em;
  margin-top: 3em;
  box-shadow: rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.15) 0px 0.5rem 1rem 0px;
  padding: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2rem;
}
.present-img {
  width: 35em;
  height: 20em;
}
.present-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.present-content {
  width: 45%;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  padding-top: 2em;
}
.present-title {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-left: 4em;
}
.present-parag {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 2rem;
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.present-link {
  font-size: 22px;
  color: rgb(0, 82, 204);
}
.present-link:hover {
  color: rgb(42, 95, 175);
}
.grow {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.grow-con {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  grid-auto-rows: 1rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 2em;
  margin-bottom: 8.3rem;
}
.grow-opening {
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  max-width: 1095px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
.grow-part {
  width: 18.5em;
  background-color: rgb(250, 251, 252);
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  height: 20rem;
}
.grow-title {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.grow-button {
  position: relative;
  top: 14%;
  width: 12rem;
  height: 3.2rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 101, 255);
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 350ms;
}
.slider-con2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.button-packet {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: end;
  width: 70rem;
  padding-right: 3rem;
}
.button-con {
  margin-left: 50rem;
  width: 4.9rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.button-con2 {
  margin-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
.button-2 {
  border-radius: 100px;
  border: none;
}
.radio-buttons {
  height: 8px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: none;
  transition: 1000ms;
}
.selected-radio {
  width: 50px;
}
.slider-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 480px;
  width: 1090px;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg fill='none' height='272' width='773' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' %3E%3Cpath d='M351.53 186.369c0-53.88-28.777-83.707-84.412-83.707h-.96c11.511-29.826 48.921-45.22 97.842-48.107V-33c-126.619 6.735-196.643 77.934-196.643 185.694 0 85.631 40.288 119.306 94.964 119.306 54.677 0 89.209-32.713 89.209-85.631Zm-203.357 0c0-53.88-28.777-83.707-84.413-83.707h-.959c11.51-29.826 48.921-45.22 97.842-48.107V-33C34.024-26.265-36 44.934-36 152.694-36 238.325 4.288 272 58.964 272s89.209-32.713 89.209-85.631Z' fill='url(%23b)' opacity='.15' /%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3ClinearGradient id='b' x1='290.667' y1='-33' x2='141.42' y2='307.405' gradientUnits='userSpaceOnUse' %3E%3Cstop stop-color='%23f99cdb' /%3E%3Cstop stop-color='%236554c0' offset='1' /%3E%3C/linearGradient%3E%3C/defs%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  box-shadow: rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.2) 0px 3px 5px,
    rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.31) 0px 0px 1px;
  margin-bottom: 10rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 2000ms;
}
.slider-element {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left-element {
  width: 760px;
  padding-left: 2rem;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}
.right-element {
  width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(60deg, rgb(101, 84, 192), rgb(249, 156, 219));
  color: white;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.3em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.3em;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  font-weight: lighter;
}
.right-title {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-left: 0.7em;
}
.price-con {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.price-opening {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}
.price-Op-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.price-op-parag {
  font-size: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.price-op-button {
  background-color: rgb(0, 101, 255);
  color: white;
  padding: 0.9em 1rem;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.price-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20em;
}
.packet {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  width: 15%;
  height: 29rem;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(180, 179, 179);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(180, 179, 179);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(180, 179, 179);
  padding: 1rem;
}
.price-tag {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.price {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.time {
  color: rgb(80, 95, 121);
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
.explanation {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: auto;
}
.exp-1 {
  padding-bottom: 2.9rem;
}
.price-button {
  width: 37%;
  height: 3rem;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 17px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 184, 217);
  background-color: white;
  transition: 350ms;
}
.price-button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(230, 252, 255);
}
.price-link {
  color: rgb(42, 95, 175);
}
.present-link:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 82, 204);
}
.butt1 {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,900&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="trello.css">
</head>
<body class="body">
    <div class="show-con void">
        <div class="section-2">
            <div class="opening-2">
                <p class="sec-name">TRELLO 101</p>
                <p class="title">A productivity powerhouse</p>
                <p class="opening-parag">Simple, flexible, and powerful. All it takes are boards, lists,
                    and cards to get a clear view of who’s doing what and what needs to get done.
                    Learn more in our <a href="#">guide for getting started.</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="container-2 ">
                <div class="sec-2-part">
                    <div class=" conpart-1 conpart curver-div">
                        <p class="con-header">Boards</p>
                        <div class="con-content">Trello boards keep tasks organized and work moving forward.
                            In a glance, see everything from “things to do” to “aww yeah, we did it!”</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="conpart-2 conpart curver-div">
                        <p class="con-header">List</p>
                        <div class="con-content">The different stages of a task. Start as simple as To Do,
                            Doing or Done—or build a workflow custom fit to your team’s needs.
                            There’s no wrong way to Trello.</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="conpart-3 conpart curver-div">
                        <p class="con-header">Cards</p>
                        <div class="con-content">Cards represent tasks and ideas and hold all the
                            information to get the job done. As you make progress, move cards across
                            lists to show their status.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sec-2-conpic curver-div">
                    <div class="sec-2-inner">
                      <div class="conpics conpic-1"><img class="conpicture"
                        src="https://images.ctfassets.net/rz1oowkt5gyp/3N2U3C71rApm61cGFxnc2E/970b010002488a09a420282df5e7b43a/Carousel_Image_Boards_2x.png?w=1536&fm=webp"
                        alt="picture"></div>
                    <div class="conpics conpic-2"><img class="conpicture"
                        src="https://images.ctfassets.net/rz1oowkt5gyp/4U0VUZYX2tQmB5KVGxBabp/7321ac088fe8ec39dbe3069c47d7df99/Carousel_Image_Lists_2x.png?w=1536&fm=webp"
                        alt="picture"></div>
                    <div class="conpics conpic-3"><img class="conpicture"
                        src="https://images.ctfassets.net/rz1oowkt5gyp/26CA6JZeRgoOK4nuRHnIlY/060702a80cf7c3be3651d9297d196267/Carousel_Image_Cards_2x.png?w=1536&fm=webp"
                        alt="picture"></div>  
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="trello.js"></script>

</div>

</html>
```

hi guys my problem is that when skipping slider using conparts elemenst on left side, when clicking conpart-3 after clicking conpart-2, the slider works wrongly. if ı click to conpart-3 while slider show conpart-1 there wont be a problem. once this problem occurs it just mess up entire slider. you will see it more clearly once you what ı told

ı was trying to copy a webpage,you guys will see what ı wanted to achieve if you open link and scroll down a little

https://trello.com/home

Comment: Hello, I edited your snippet, better to not include header and body tags, only the content. Now there is a javascript error (`sec_2_inner` variable not declared), can you fix it please?

Comment: @Yogi , ı edited code please take a look again

Comment: @Kaddath, ı am sorry, ı fix it. please a look again

Comment: Not sure why you are calling this a "slider", it's more like a tabbed interface. And any actual sliding won't happen here to begin with, if that's what `onpic.style.transition = "scrollLeft 0.5s ease-in-out";` was supposed to achieve. You can only transition CSS properties, but `scrollLeft` isn't one, that's a JavaScript property of the element.

Comment: @CBroe ı was trying to copy this web page, you'll what ı wanted to achieve after you open web page and scroll-down a little

Comment: `conpic.scrollLeft = scrollAmount;` - if you log that value to the console, then you will see that it changes drastically, even if you click the _same_ tab repeatedly.